# How to import a local file in my main package

Tags: go

Let's say, I have the following structure.

```
export $GOPATH = ~/workspace/go
```

Directory-Tree:

```
~/workspace
+ go
  + src
    + example
      + exp1
        - main.go
        - client.go
        + utils
          - my_utils.go
```

In the file `main.go` i'd like to import 'client.go' and 'utils/my_utils.go'.
How to do that?

```
import {
   "./client.go"
}
```

will give me

> local import "./client.go" in non-local package

The same happens with any other file in subdirectories like my "utils" folder.

I've read a lot about this error message and about the GOPATH. However, coming from NodeJS and PHP and C++ I really still don't understand this concept of how GoLang will handle file imports and need some further clarification here.

I've read also that people where going to import everything from "GitHub.com", but it makes no sense for me to first push my code to GitHub before I can test it in my local project.

By the way, I'm also curious why `go get` will not fetch all sub-dependencies together with the specific library that will be fetch with `go get`?

Comment: You cannot import files. Only packages can be imported. Read "How to Write Go Code".

Comment: [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) steps you through creating and importing a package. Please read through that documentation first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read also that people where going to import everything from "GitHub.com", but it makes no sense for me to first push my code to GitHub before I can test it in my local project.

You don't have to push it anywhere before you can test it. You only have to choose what your import path is, and then put your code in `GOPATH` accordingly (or use `go mod init` with Go 1.11+, which lets you place your code anywhere in the filesystem you want). But you still have to pick that import path — even if you decide to change it later.

> By the way, I'm also curious why go get will not fetch all sub-dependencies together with the specific library that will be fetch with go get?

It does.

Comment: My code is in $GOPATH/src/$projectName. There is already a folder called "GitHub.com" instead of $projectName, both exists next to each other. I'm confused